# returning a list from a user function using group_by in R

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have a data.frame, I would like to group the data by one of the columns and then apply a function, which operates on the remaining columns of the data. The function returns a list of mixed objects.

If I was just returning one value from the group I know that I could use something like:

```
df %>% group_by(Column_1) %>% summarise(my_function)
```

I also know that I could perform operations on a list using the lapply which will happily return a list. I'm just not sure how to combines these two pieces of knowledge to acheive my desired result.

example code added, userFunction and data are representitive, but should give a good enough idea of what I want.

```
userFunction <- function(carData){
  return(list(
    a = carData$am * carData$carb,
    b = plot(carData$disp ~ carData$carb),
    c = mean(carData$drat)
  ))
}

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(userFunction)
```

I'd like to get back a list of lenght the number of factors in the columns i group_by. In the list should be a, b and c.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide some sample input data and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work as I was want.

```
this <- by(mtcars, mtcars$am, userFunction)
```